# Angular 2 calling a Typescript function from Jquery causes uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript, angular

I have a component with input text field to which I have attached an input event listener using JQuery. When the value of the input changes I want to call a Typescript function but it throws an uncaught TypeError.

Here is my code:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'setting-priority',
    template: '<input [(ngModel)]="priority" class="setting-priority" type="text">'
})

export class SettingPriorityComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() priority: number;
    @Output() prioChanged: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('input').on('input', function() {
            // Here I will pass the changed value to onChange function
            this.onChange();
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) { 
        this.prioChanged.emit(this.priority);
    }

    // In this function I will receive the value and assign it to the priority variable
    onChange() {
        console.log("onchange!");
    }
}
```

I'm using Jquery because the input value will be set programmatically - in this case Angular's Change Detection doesn't work [Details here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3053-changing-directive-inputs-programmatically-won-t-trigger-ngonchanges-in-angularjs-2-beta-9.htm)

When I trigger the input event, I receive an **Uncaught TypeError: this.onChange is not a function**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use an arrow function. This way you could use the lexical this (that corresponds to the component instance):

```
jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('input').on('input', () => {
  this.onChange();
});
```

See this link for more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Works great! Thank you!
By the way, I found another one method - to bind a JavaScript variable to the angular context and then call functions using it:

`var self = this;`
`jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('input').on('input', function {
            self.onChange();
        });`

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid using jQuery in Angular2.

A more angulary approach to get a reference to an element would be

```
@Component({
    selector: 'setting-priority',
    template: '<input #prio [(ngModel)]="priority" class="setting-priority" type="text">'
})
export class SettingPriorityComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('prio') priority;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.priority);
  }
}
```

but for adding an event handler you just need:

```
template: '<input [(ngModel)]="priority" (input)="onChange()" class="setting-priority" type="text">'
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm using Jquery-UI to make a table sortable using drag-and-drop because I didn't find such a simple solution for native Angular 2.